# SAS fill missing values

Tags: sas, retain

I have the following data:

```
data test ;
INPUT id st end ;
datalines ;
1 17 .
1 17 .
1 17 17.5
1 17 .
1 17 .
2 15 .
2 15 .
2 15 .
2 15 .
2 15 15.75
run ;

data test2 ;
set test ;
dur = end - st ;
run ;
```

I would like to fill in the missing values of "dur" by "id" to give:

```
id   st   end   dur
1    17    .    17.5
1    17    .    17.5
1    17   17.5  17.5
1    17    .    17.5
2    15    .    15.75
2    15    .    15.75
2    15    .    15.75
2    15    .    15.75
2    15   15.75 15.75
```

As the rows are not in any order to use `proc sort` and `retain`, how can I replace the missing values of "dur"? (Without using a merge as the real dataset is extremely large).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `proc sort` and `retain` as you say to achieve the right dur column, however it doesn't give you the same structure as your example output:

```
proc sort data = test;
  by id descending end;
run;

data test2 ;
  set test ;
  by id;
  retain dur;
  if first.id then dur = end - st ;
run;
```

Then `test2` looks like:

```
id  st  end     dur
1   17  17.5    0.5 
1   17  .       0.5 
1   17  .       0.5 
1   17  .       0.5 
1   17  .       0.5 
2   15  15.75   0.75    
2   15  .       0.75    
2   15  .       0.75    
2   15  .       0.75    
2   15  .       0.75
```

However, the `proc sort` could be pretty slow if your data becomes too large. A `proc SQL` method may be more useful:

```
proc sql;
  create table test2 as
  select id, st, end, max(end-st) as dur
  from test
  group by id;
quit;
```